# Min-width does not work on nested flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

This code has min-width working.

```css
.list-header {
  display: flex;
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #ececec;
}

.list-component {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 24px;
  min-width: 0;
}

.header-container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
}

.header-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 0;
}

span {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-header">
  <div class="list-component">
    <div class="header-container">
      <div class="header-text">
        <span>long long long long long long text</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, if you set `align-items: flex-start;` to `.header-text`, min-width will not work. Here is the code.

```css
.list-header {
  display: flex;
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #ececec;
}

.list-component {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 24px;
  min-width: 0;
}

.header-container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
}

.header-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;　/* ADD THIS!! */
  min-width: 0;
}

span {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-header">
  <div class="list-component">
    <div class="header-container">
      <div class="header-text">
        <span>long long long long long long text</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I thought that `flex-direction` had an effect and changed`min-width: 0;`to`min-height: 0;`, but it did not work out.

Also, I read the specification of this, but I could not do anything.

- https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#min-size-opt
- https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#align-items-property

I am the first time to see this phenomenon.
Why does this happen? Is there a solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not with `min-width` as you may think because if you add border you will see that all the elements aren't overflowing (due to `min-width:0`) and only the last span is overflowing

```css
.list-header {
  display: flex;
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #ececec;
  border:2px solid red;
}

.list-component {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 24px;
  min-width: 0;
  border:2px solid blue;
}

.header-container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
  border:2px solid green;
}

.header-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:flex-start;
  min-width: 0;
  border:2px solid yellow;
}

span {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  border:2px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-header">
  <div class="list-component">
    <div class="header-container">
      <div class="header-text">
        <span>long long long long long long text</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So we can simplify your issue like follow:

```css
.header-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  min-width: 0;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  width: 150px;
}

span {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-text">
  <span>long long long long long long text</span>
</div>
```

Why `align-items` break you code? Simply because the initial value was `stretch` which mean that you span will have its width to be stretched to fit the width of the flex container (like doing `width:100%`). By chaging the alignment you no more have this feature and you create the overflow.

To fix this you can simply use `width:100%` instead. The main idea is to have a property that will force the width to be full width of the parent element so that you limit the width of the element thus the ellipsis will work:

```css
.header-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  min-width: 0;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  width: 150px;
}

span {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-text">
  <span>long long long long long long text</span>
</div>
```

And with your initial code:

```css
.list-header {
  display: flex;
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #ececec;
  border:2px solid red;
}

.list-component {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 24px;
  min-width: 0;
  border:2px solid blue;
}

.header-container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
  border:2px solid green;
}

.header-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:flex-start;
  min-width: 0;
  border:2px solid yellow;
}

span {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  border:2px solid;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-header">
  <div class="list-component">
    <div class="header-container">
      <div class="header-text">
        <span>long long long long long long text</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It was very easy to understand!!

Answer (score 2):

Add `overflow:hidden` to the `.header-container` div:

```css
.list-header {
  display: flex;
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #ececec;
}

.list-component {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 24px;
  min-width: 0;
}

.header-container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;　/* ADD THIS!! */
  min-width: 0;
}

span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-header">
  <div class="list-component">
    <div class="header-container">
      <div class="header-text">
        <span>long long long long long long text</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.
However, I would like to set text-overflow.(dotted line)
Also, I am looking for why this phenomenon is occurring. Do not you know what caused the problem?